# Make chat message body scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following chat HTMl

```
<div class="chat" id="chat_window" style="display:none">
<div class="title"> HEADER </div>
<div id="chat_box">

     <div class="conver chat_two">
        <p> HEY HOW ARE YOU</p>
     </div>

</div>
</div>
```

When ever a chat comes, I append this to chat_box div

```
<div class="conver chat_two">
     <p> IAM FINE</p>
</div>
```

But the whole div is going up when chat increases as below image

[image]

How do I make the chat box with constant size and the messages to scroll inside the window?

Answer (score 0):

```
#chat_window {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give a fixed height and overflow : auto to chat_box div.
And give a height to chat_two / conver class.

e.g.

```
#chat_box{
  height : 100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.chat_two{
   height : 50px; 
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gztqza7j/1/

Comment: Is there anyway to make chat_two div to appear at bottom. When adding the div, the scroll is going up

Comment: May be after adding the div try to focus it using focus API. you need to provide tabindex as 0 to focus newly added div.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your chat_box

```
#chat_box
{
    overflow-y :auto;
}
```